# How to increase MemCacheProtocol's MAX_KEY_LENGTH?

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to change MAX_KEY_LENGTH
I tried it with the following example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.protocols.memcache import MemCacheProtocol, DEFAULT_PORT
import string
from twisted.python import log
import sys
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
def cb(response):
    log.msg(response) 
d = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, MemCacheProtocol
    ).connectTCP('localhost', DEFAULT_PORT)
def doSomething(proto):
    # Here you call the memcache operations
    return proto.set(string.ascii_letters*5, string.ascii_letters*5)

MemCacheProtocol.MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 1000
d.addCallback(doSomething)
d.addBoth(cb)
d.addBoth(lambda ignore: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

I am keep getting this failure:

```
[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.protocols.memcache.ClientError'>: bad command line format!
```

I am guessing not all message is sent to the memcache server and as a result it returns this failure
What do I need to do in order to store keys with length greater than 250 in memcache?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are modifying it too late. Try this:

```
class MyMemCacheProtocol(MemCacheProtocol):

    MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 1000
```

Now use this class in ClientCreator() call instead of the original.

Comment: Did you also modify the settings of the memcache you are talking with? I believe the default maximum key size on the memcache side is 250 characters.

Comment: The original code was not setting the new limit too late.  The problem is only making the server agree with the new limit.  As the (strangely?) deleted answer by gperetin suggested, the exception would be "Key too long" if the problem were coming out of the Twisted memcache client implementation.